# Default threshold in cross-validation metrics - h2o R package

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o, gbm

I created an cartesian grid of GBMs using `h2o` package in R and saved cross-validation metrics for each model in a data frame. So, for each model, I stored the results given in `model@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary`.

What is the threshold used to calculate F1 and F2 scores, precision, recall and specificity in `model@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary`? Is there a default value?

Comment: In the old days of SO, you could nominate a question fro closing by way of migration to another group and fill in a blank to nominate a group. That facility seems to have been lost and now the migration destination is a closed panel. This seems more a question for Data Science (since it doesn't actually have any code or data in it), but that's not an option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should go to Data Science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the threshold for a specific metric by using:

`find_threshold_by_max_metric`

api documentation is [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?#h2o.model.binomial.H2OBinomialModel.find_threshold_by_max_metric)